# Arp attack from router?

Tags: wifi

I have some strange issue with local unsecured public wifi network. Whenever I connect to it, I receive  following messages in log from dhcpcd: "Warning, hardware adress X claims IP" where hardware address belongs to router and ip address is my adress which was obtained from the router.

Being curious, I have run wireshark to save some traffic and inspected it with networkminer. Surprisingly, networkminer reported than some packets were possibly arp-spoofed by mac adress which belong to router. Networkminer reported that mac address say X, was changed to Y. When I looked at the dump in wireshark, it was written that packet from clearly not local ip was delivered with physical address Y (router). Just for example, I receive tcp packets from 141.AAA..., 89.BBBB, 76.CCCC which have router Y hardware address, which networkminer says were arp spoofed.

So, basically: 1) Why router claims my ip after it was assigned to me? 2) How networkminer detected that mac adress of some packets were spoofed?

Comment: probably someone using a static IP address in your network. release and renew your IP address to see if it fixes it.

Comment: why are you running DHCP server ? you jst need to have dhclient to get ip address ? plz stop that and again post the logs

Comment: 1. This is definetely not someone using static IP, because the issue repeats each time I connect to internet and each time I obtain different IP. 2. DHCPCD is a client.